# Replicate a numpy list m times

Tags: python, list, numpy

I am trying to pair two different databases of images that I have in python (lets say database A and database B, they are stored in list of numpy arrays). For the database A I have x images (for example 6) and for database B y images (for example 78). Each image from database A is correspond to 78/6 = 13 images from database B and the order is the same. Thus,

```
A    B
--------------
1    [1, 13]
2    [14, 26]
3    [27, 39]
4    [38, 52] 
5    [51, 65] 
6    [66, 78]
```

What I want to do is to replicate each image from database A 13 times in order to have the same number of images with database B. The problem is that those amount of numbers are not fixed (x and y). Therefore,

```
len1 = len(database_A)
len2 = len(database_B)
m = round(len2/len1)
```

How can I return a replicate m times the elements of the database list A (m times the image 1 then m times the image 2 etc.).

**EDIT:** Sometimes the division produces some module. How can I handle that module. There is the case i have for database A 6 images while for database B 68 and that produce mod = 2. I need in that case to store only 66 images from both databases.

Comment: What's desired output, btw, i don't fully understand the question

Comment: A list for database A with 78 images (the same size as in database B) where every image will be replicated m  times (in the example 13) 13 times image 1 then 13 times image 2 etc..

Comment: Seriously?  Changing the question when you've already checked an answer?

Comment: Your lists aren't (native) Python, they're numpy. Retitling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the images are in `(n, x, y)` or `(n, x, y, RGB)` shaped arrays:

```
np.repeat(A, B.shape[0] // A.shape[0], axis = 0)
```

If you really want to keep lists, I still recommend doing the repetition in `numpy`

```
list(np.repeat(np.array(A), len(B) // len(A), axis = 0))
```

if you really want list comprehension

```
A = [a for a in A for _ in range(len(B) // len(A))]
if len(B) % lenA > 0:
    B = B[:-(len(B) % len(A))]
```

Comment: The images are in lists, so for the database A i have a list with 6 elements each one a numpy array while in the second list for database B 78 numpy items that correspond to images.

Comment: I'd recommend throwing those lists in `np.array(...)` so you can process them in parallel then.

Comment: Haha, this answer is much better than mine. I made it way too complex. Nice! +1

Comment: @konstantin, is there a reason you unchecked my answer?

Comment: I figure out that my question did not cover what I want to ask from first hand.

Answer (score 1):

I toned down the example to have A have 3 images and imagine each needs to be replicated 7 times (`m==7`). IIUC, this should do the job:

```
import numpy as np

def flatten_list_of_lists(replicate):
    for item in replicate:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            yield from flatten_list_of_lists(item)
        else:
            yield item

A = [np.arange(9).reshape(3,3), np.arange(28).reshape(7,4), np.arange(20).reshape(2,10)]
m = 7
replicate = [[x]*7 for x in A]
result = list(flatten_list_of_lists(replicate))
print([x.shape for x in result])
```

which outputs shapes ("images" are a little beefy to output):

```
[(3, 3), (3, 3), (3, 3), (3, 3), (3, 3), (3, 3), (3, 3), (7, 4), (7, 4), (7, 4), (7, 4), (7, 4), (7, 4), (7, 4), (2, 10), (2, 10), (2, 10), (2, 10), (2, 10), (2, 10), (2, 10)]
```

as desired (each is replicated 7 times in the `result` list)